# Как сконвертировать код из .sh в .bat

Tags: bash, shell, bat, sh, batik

мне нужно преобразовать код из файла **.sh** в файл **.bat** соответственно изменив синтаксис.

Исходный код

```bash
#!/bin/sh

palette="/tmp/palette.png"
run="`pwd`/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"

filters="fps=25,scale=0:-1:flags=lanczos"
 
$run -v warning -i $1 -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
$run -v warning -i $1 -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

то что я сам попытался сделать, поискав решение в сети

```cs
SET PALETTE = "/tmp/palette.png"
SET RUN = "'%CD%'/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"

SET FILTERS = "fps=25, scale=0:-1:flags=lanczos"

%RUN% -v warning -i $1 -vf %FILTERS%" ,palettegen" -y %PALETTE%
%RUN% -v warning -i $1 -i %PALETTE% -lavfi %FILTERS% " [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

Но мой вариант не работает. Подскажите где я ошибся.

Comment: вот здесь `"/tmp/palette.png"` - под виндой такого пути нет (и в принципе в  бат файле быть не может). Пропишите туда правильный путь.

Comment: Слэши тоже не особо пашут. Надо на бэкслэши поменять.

Comment: @KoVadim Я поменял слеши попробовал настроить относительный путь, но это все равно не срабатывает 

https://gist.github.com/pareylook/ea6fbf6cb6c09399c3f76a477832baf7

Сразу извиняюсь не могу как в комментарии работает форматирование кода

Comment: попробуйте распечатать команды, которые в результате получаются (я запутался в этих всех переменных:). А потом попробовать их выполнить напрямую. И там  будет понятно